# python - loading @hybrid_property of SQLAlchemy ORM to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

**TLDR** DataFrame.from_records() ignores @hybrid_property of sqlalchemy ORM

Hello, I want to be able to populate pandas.DataFrame from sqlalchemy objects.
I have a class which is defined like that:

```
class Cat_24(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cat_24"
    ad_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = Column(String(128))
    description = Column(String(8192))
    offer_type = Column(String(16))
...
    prices = relationship("AdPrice", backref=backref("cat_24"))
...
    @hybrid_property
    def last_price(self):
        if self.prices:
            return self.prices[-1].price
        else:
            return None

    @last_price.expression
    def last_price(cls):
        # return cls.prices[-1].price
        return (
            select([AdPrice.price])
            .where(cls.ad_id == AdPrice.ad_id)
            .order_by(AdPrice.price.desc())
            .limit(1)
            .as_scalar()
        )
```

When I tries to select rows and load them:

```
tmp = session.query(Cat_24).filter_by(offer_type='Продам').all()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( tmp )
```

I can see only regular Columns in dataframe, last_price will not be loaded.
So question, how to load hybrid_property in DataFrame?

**Update** ugly solution which I figured out:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for column in self.__table__.columns:
            yield column.name, getattr(self, column.name)

        if self.aditional_attrs:
            for attr in self.aditional_attrs:
                yield attr, getattr(self, attr)
```

self.aditional_attrs is a tuple with hybrid_property names which I want to get, after that tmp query from the above can be converted into list of dictionaries:

```
tmp = list(map(dict,tmp))
```

Comment: Are you manually maintaining the list of additional attributes? If so, and you want to pull them out dynamically you should be able to use `hybrid_property_names = [x for x in Thing.__dict__ if isinstance(Thing.__dict__[x], hybrid_property)]`

Comment: I don't want to maintain list of attributes at all, I want to be able read them into DataFrame as well as other Columns. __iter__ just an ugly solution which I don't like.

Comment: I am trying to do the same, you can add the column by modifying the query to include the hybrid property, by using sessions.query(MyModel, MyModel.my_h_propery). This however gets some weird column name.